# UIPopover equal screen width

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I need to make popover size Equal device screen width, is it possible? I try such code:

```
ShareViewController *shareVC = [[ShareViewController alloc] init];
sharePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:shareVC];
sharePopover.popoverContentSize = shareVC.view.frame.size; // width there is 1024 i'm sure
sharePopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y + 10, sender.frame.size.width, sender.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

also i tried to set width in `popoverContentSize` by number like `1024`, or bigger, but no effect, i have some spaces in left and right, how can i fix it?

Here screenshot of problem:
http://uaimage.com/image/c54d471d

Comment: Consider using something other than a popover if you want this sort of complete control. Why not a presented view controller? In iOS 7 and 8 it easy to make presented view appear in front of your main view, just like a popover. What you have doesn't even look like a popover, so it isn't clear why you want to use one at all.

Comment: @matt it's more comfortable in my situation to use popover, because i don't need to program animation to show and hide him, but it's not the main problem, in sum i decide to use popover, if there is no solution i'll use UIView or UIViewController, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's UIPopoverController documentation, regarding the 'popoverLayoutMargins' property (can be found here: [UIPopoverController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/popoverLayoutMargins):

```
The margins that define the portion of the screen in which  
it is permissible to display the popover....
...The edge inset values are measured in points from the edges of the screen,  
relative to the current device orientation...  
...The default edge insets are 10 points along each edge.
```

Try adding the following and see if it helps:

```
sharePopover.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Perfectly works for IOS7, but not working for IOS8, but it's better than nothing, thank you.

Comment: @matt documentation doesn't say anything about it being deprecated in iOS 8. is it a bug?

Comment: @AMI289 I certainly regard it as a bug.